# Using Javascript to get value from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

my html code:

```
<li id='category-10'>
<label class="selectit">
<input value="10" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-10" /> Developmental
</label>
</li>
```

my javascript code:

```
function onCategoryClick() {
 $(".selectit").click(function(e){
    var categoryValue = $(e.target).text();
    alert("The value is " + categoryValue);
 });
}
```

This returns me the string "The value is Developmental" but what I want is "The value is 10"
I'm new to Javascript, how would I go about targeting the value field in the input, instead of the text?

I've also tried

```
var categoryValue = $(e.target > input).value;
```

But this doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(e.target).text();
```

try

```
$(this).find('#in-category-10').val();
```

Here `e.target` corresponds to the `label` . And it has  text 'Developmental' and also a nested input element.
So you need to use find to access it. (If there is no id)

But `ID` is supposed to be unique on the page. So to access the element you can directly used the id selector

```
var categoryValue = $('#in-category-10').val();
```

And remember that input has no `text` property. Need to use the `val` method

Comment: Thanks @Sushanth! Using .val(); did the trick! However the reason i'm using $(e.target) is because I have many list items with different id's, <li id='category-1'>, <li id='category-2'> <li id='category-3'> etc. I want to write one script that handles them all, regardless of which checkbox you click, it will return saying "The value is .." and then whatever the value of that checkbox is.

Comment: @crusarovid.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: You can avoid use `this` instead `e.target`  .. This should be good enough `$(".selectit").click(function(e){
    var categoryValue = $(this).find('input').val();
    alert("The value is " + categoryValue);
 });
` .. This will work for the markup that you were referring to